# CakePHP. Change element in array

Tags: php, cakephp

```
$this->paginate = array(
     'limit' => 5,
     'conditions' => ''
);


$this->paginate['conditions'] = array(
     'name LIKE' => '%a'
);
```

and them notice:

```
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property EmployeeCvsController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\EmployeeCvsController.php, line 137]
```

Could someone explain me why I can't change order element from array?

Comment: Possible dublicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Indirect+modification+of+overloaded+property

Comment: Post your relatively complete code of the method you are using.

Comment: Generally it's all. Except that I read data and set it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html), you can either

1) specify the `$paginate` variable in the controller (not within an action):

```
public $paginate = array();
```

or 2) just put it in one array instead of two:

```
    $this->paginate = array(
         'limit' => 5,
         'conditions' => array(
            'name LIKE' => '%a'
         )
    );
```

or 3) use `$paginate` instead of `$this->paginate` on the second reference:

```
$paginate['conditions'] = array(
   'name LIKE' => '%a'
);
```